# What is the best way to delete all indices in neo4j?

Tags: database, indexing, graph, neo4j, cypher

I want to delete all available indices in neo4j in one go, so that database is totally clean and I can create new indices.

`DROP INDEX *` didnt work in cypher.

I dont want to iterate through every index name and drop it using neo4j clients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) installed, you can use [apoc.schema.assert()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_schema_2). This is usually used to assert that certain constraints and indexes are present (and create them if not), and optionally to keep or drop all other indexes and constraints not otherwise provided as parameters.

In your case, if you want to wipe out all indexes and constraints, just supply empty maps for the indexes and constraints, and it should wipe out your schema completely:

```
CALL apoc.schema.assert({},{})
```

Note that this currently doesn't handle composite indexes or node key constraints, we'll need to adjust for that.